# jQuery html() function doesn't make text bold

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to make a part of a text that is to be displayed by my jQuery script bold. So far I tried this:

```
$('.task-name').html('<b>Task:</b>'+'All');
```

This is where the text is to be displayed in my html code:

```
<p class="task-name"> Task: no filter selected.</p>
```

When I make this, the text is displayed like this:

> Task: all

And not:

> **Task:** all

I don't know why this isn't working, since this is the syntax for this (see [this example](https://www.bitdegree.org/learn/best-code-editor/jquery-innerhtml-example-1) --> this is for italics, but I'm assuming bold works the same way)

Comment: which browser do you use? in chrome work.

Comment: You can use css to do styling right ?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I use Chrome, but now it's working!

Comment: @Saroj yeah I know, but in this case it's a filter where the selected filters are to be displayed for the user, so I do this with jQuery!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to see if something if overriding the b tag style ?

You could try to add it yourself:

```
b {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Or even use the [`<strong>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_strong.asp) tag, which is usually more used.

But I think the best would be to use a custom class with a bold style like :

```
$('.task-name').html('<span class="text-bold">Task:</span>'+'All');
```

And your css file

```
.text-bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: I just did, StackOverflow asked me to wait 5 minutes :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this code using jQuery's css functions

```js
<p class="task-name">Task: no filter selected.</p>

<script>
    $('.task-name').html('<span class="bold-span">Task:</span>'+'All');
    $('.bold').css("font-weight","Bold");
</script>
```